# Find the missing domino

Tags: pattern, dominoes

In my last school-class I did a logic-test with 48 exercises about finding the missing dominoes. I'm sure about 47, but this one broke my head, and I don't know yet the answer:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> 3,6 since the sum of diagonally opposite squares sum up to 6.

So the picture is

> [image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't realized that... good eyes!

Comment: Why does the 3 go on the inside and the 6 on the outside? Or are there two correct solutions?

Comment: The inner squares are in correspondence, and the outer squares are in correspondence.

Comment: @Improve Very good! :) )  But mathematically and logically it still could be *anything* with a solid explanation.

Comment: Of course, I dont intend to claim that it is the only correct solution, but it is one that seemed natural enough to me.

Comment: @Improve I think the only **solid** answer is that it's not a very good logic test!  But I can see why yours is probably the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 2):

It could be *anything* but let's guess:

> You have a total of 15 on the inside circle and 12 on the outside circle.
>  So say they have to add up to the same number for some obscure reason.
>  Remember it could be *anything* - so let's take a wild pot shot at:
>  We have 2 dominoes that total 8 and two that total 4 and *one* that totals 3.
>  So for symmetry, lets say the missing domino has to total 3.
>  So it's blank on the inside circle and 3 on the outside circle.
>  For a total of 15 on both the inside and outside circle and two matching sums all around.

Answer (score 2):

2,5 Two dots are added to each square on the domino directly opposite. [image]